# Chrome Extension Font Awesome won't display in Shadow Root

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

My chrome extension appends a div to the page using the shadow root so that no other styles affect my div.

But because I do this, my Font Awesome icons don't display. I have tried implementing what other questions suggested about using @font-face, but it still doesn't work.

```
content =
    "<style>" +
      "@font-face {" +
        "font-family: 'FontAwesome';" +
        "src: url('" + chrome.extension.getURL('Alpha_Extension_Design/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0') + "');" +
        "src: url('" + chrome.extension.getURL('Alpha_Extension_Design/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') + "') format('embedded-opentype'),"+
        "url('" + chrome.extension.getURL('Alpha_Extension_Design/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') + "') format('woff2')," +
        "url('" + chrome.extension.getURL('Alpha_Extension_Design/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') + "') format('woff')," +
        "url('" + chrome.extension.getURL('Alpha_Extension_Design/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') + "') format('truetype')," +
        "url('" + chrome.extension.getURL('Alpha_Extension_Design/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') +"') format('svg');" +
        "font-weight: normal;" +
        "font-style: normal;" +
      "}" +
    "</style>" + content;

shadow.innerHTML = content;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Font Awesome works just fine if I append the stylesheet to the header of the page I am on and if I'm not using the shadow root.

Comment: Have you listed the fonts in ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)? If yes, then maybe it's a bug/limitation of shadowDOM in Chrome in which case use https://crbug.com to open a ticket

Comment: I have listed the fonts in the web_accessible_resources. It doesn't seem like a bug. Other extensions such as Mini Mammoth(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mini-mammoth/mnodmjdgoadhalodifblaaikgcfgchfb?hl=en-US) have a shadow root with @font-face. But I'm not sure how they did it.

Comment: As you can see in that extenion's cSS file they're using base64 encoding for the fonts. Try it as well, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert Font Awesome to base64 and use it. Although I did find this: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/294 . I followed what Xero said concerning uploading the ttf to font-squirrel. After following his instructions I received a folder with Font Awesome in base64, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know? The example is given in that github issue and in that extension's CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

All everything is correct.

you need add style with `@font-face` to parent document

```
$(document.head).append( $('<style/>', {html: function() { return '@font-face ...'; }}) )
```

[image: adding to head]

and prepend style with @import fontawesome.css; to root

[image: adding to root]

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely useful!